# Problem with libicu66 during installation php-intl extension on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: dependencies, php7, 21.10

```
sudo apt install php7.0-intl
```

Output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0-intl : Depends: libicu66 (>= 66.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Previous versions never had a problem with this dependency

Any ideas?..

```
> uname -a

Linux ###### 5.13.0-21-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 19 08:59:28 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Panic canceled

just download [binary](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu66_66.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb)

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu66_66.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

And install it manually:

```
sudo dpkg -i libicu66_66.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

After that you can install php-intl:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
```

Now the installation is successful

Comment: panic eliminated! Smooth answer, thanks. Works for me installing R

Comment: Works on newer PHP/Ubuntu situ's too and using `apt-get install php-intl` will get the latest version of php-intl.